# Why doesn't my tub faucet provide hot water?

Tags: water

My Delta freestanding tub faucet doesn't get hot. Took off handle and turn knob inside to adjust temp, but notice it still isn't much warmer. Noticed I had to turn towards cold to make it hotter. Could supply lines be be the issue? If reversed will the water be hotter?

Comment: Please revise to add more information about your hardware than just a brand name. A photo would be great. A model number would be better. Reversing supplies isn't a solution. It sounds like the anti-scald feature is failing.